# how can i implement JWT token in my website?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I implemented JWT Token Authentication in React framework, It gets me token but the problem I am getting is I am not able to authenticate it on the pages which need authentication.

I tried "Authorization: Bearer " after that authenticated url,

I tried "Authorization : JWT Token token"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can do something like this :

```
const response = await axios.get('http://example.com',{ headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).